# How do I autostart jupyter notebook in appmode?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have a Jupyter Notebook with ipywidgets and [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode).

It is launched by issuing:

```
jupyter notebook nbook/demo.ipynb
```

And then clicking the Appmode button.

However, I would prefer the notebook to actually start in [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode).

Can this be done? Preferably by a command line switch or a config file stored alongside the notebook.

Regards Niels

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, just follow the instructions on how to make it permanent :

https://mdyzma.github.io/2018/06/24/running-jupyter-lab-in-application-mode/

Comment: Yes. The browser in appmode. Sorry for the confusion. What I am looking for is this appmode, hiding code cells and so on: https://github.com/oschuett/appmode